# Watson conversation does not answer even hitting intents

Tags: watson-conversation

I try to make a chatbot with Watson conversation API and always get front to same issue.
Even through a word hit to a correct intents, it does not answer anything which is supposed to response for hitting the intents.

I do not have any clue to solve this issue. does anyone have same problems?

Comment: Does your dialog workspace contain dialog nodes with conditions matching to these intents?

Comment: Thank you for reply. yes it does contain with condition matching to those intents. just like Tiger if # XXXX .  And I checked the accuracy <? intents ?> they hit over 0.9 so it must hit the the correct intents still it does not response which written in the node.

Comment: I would try to use some sample app/workspace I really can't tell what the issue might be...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your #intent is in the Trigger condition.

But in each node there is a secondary condition for each response.

If you want a default response, you can type "true" (or any text) into the response condition and click "new condition" from the drop-down. Whenever the Trigger #intent is hit, this default response will always fire.

You could add another response with response condition "@colour:red" for example which means this response will only fire when the user hits the intent #tiger AND @colour:red.